# Compare a column with every element of another column which is an array

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 columns in a postgresql table like:

```
col A            col B        col C                                     
----------      ---------   ---------                                 
2020-01-01      2024-01-01   {2020-01-01, 2020-05-01, 2022-03-01}    
2020-05-01      2021-05-01   {2020-01-01, 2020-05-01, 2022-03-01}
2022-03-01      2023-03-01   {2020-01-01, 2020-05-01, 2022-03-01}
```

col C is basically the array_agg of colA over the window. What I need to check is, for each row of col A, if the datetime is >= any of the elements of the array from col C. What is the possible solution?

Note: In my actual case there's another col D, which is the array_agg of col B. So what I'll be actually checking is col A >= any of the elements of the array from col C and col B <= any of the elements of the array from col D. I mainly don't know how to compare a value with each element from an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax here is pretty nice, you can just write

`WHERE A >= Any( C )`

If you need to do more complicated checks on the elements in an array, you can also use a generator expression to make it act like multiple rows and then write SQL against it. For example,

```sql
WHERE 0 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM unnest(C) AS elt WHERE A >= elt)
```

Would be a more elaborate (but more general) way to do the same thing.

Comment: Say, for example, I have a 2D array like this: 
`{{2019-07-01,2020-07-01},{2020-07-01,2021-07-01},{2021-07-01,2021-08-01},{2022-07-01,2023-07-01}}` -- All the 1D arrays inside represent different start dates and end dates.

I have a column called date_start and another called date_end. I want to check for each row, whether the date_start >= start date for each of the element of the array and date_end <= end date for each of the element of the array. What can be done for that?

Comment: That's a tough one! I haven't worked much with 2D arrays in SQL. You could do` SELECT ... FROM generate_series(1,array_length(colname,),1) AS i` to get the indexes of each row, and then reference both colname and i again in the WHERE clause to get the date_start and date_end?